# CanCan giving error when used with underscored names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm using CanCan for authorization, and it works fine, except for when I try and set up authorizations for any classes with underscores in the name, e.g. message_board. For example, the following works fine:

ability.rb

```
can [:read, :create, :destroy], Message do |message|
        message.user_id == user.access_id
      end
```

but when I add the following:

```
can [:create, :read], Message_board do |board|
        board.user_id == user.access_id
      end
```

when I try to do anything that requires authorization, I get the following error:

```
LoadError in TimelinesController#show 
Expected {app_name}/app/models/message_board.rb to define Message_board
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: if you don't respect the conventions, don't expect the framework to work

Comment: where is your Message_board class defined? I'd also suggest to stick to the default CamelCase notation for class names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea on how to fix this: Don't use underscores in class names.

I know this sounds a bit like the doctor in the old joke (Patient: "Doctor, it hurts when I do *this*!" Doctor: "Don't do that."), but there actually is a reason behind it.

Rails is extremely opinionated about naming conventions. Class names are expected to be upper camel case (`MessageBoard`, or `FooBarThing`). The file that contains the class is the underscored, downcase version (`message_board.rb` or `foo_bar_thing.rb`). Because this is always the case, Rails thinks it 'knows' how to convert from one to the other, and therefore it 'knows' where to look for the file containing a class with a given name. When the names don't line up the way it expects, there can be problems. It's *probably* possible to convince it to work in some other format, but I can think of no reason to do so.

Comment: I'm a bit of a rails noob, was confused about naming conventions I think! Rectified the code in the permissions, calling them MessageBoard etc, and it now works. Thanks for that.